# Change payment gateway programatically using Tyche Deposit plugin in woocommerce wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Looking for a way to change the payment gateway for scheduled future payments using Tyche Deposit plugin in woocommerce wordpress site. The first payment to be using credit card but all future payments to have an option of Bank transfer & card payment. Used code in functions.php to disable the PG for below 5000/- cart total (since most of the first payment is below this threshold) and to enable both for subsequent future payments. But its not working.

Added below code in functions. php
working well for the first payment but not for future payments..

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'show_hide_payment_methods' );
function show_hide_payment_methods( $available_gateways ) {

```
if ( WC()->cart->total <= 5000 ) {
    if ( isset($available_gateways['bacs']) ) {
        unset($available_gateways['bacs']);
    }
}
else if ( WC()->cart->total > 5000 ) {
    if ( isset($available_gateways['stripe']) ) {
        unset($available_gateways['stripe']);
    }
}
return $available_gateways;
```

}